# Minimum number of transpositions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's have two permutations $A$ and $B$ of $n$ numbers. What is the minimal number $m$ of [transpositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions) to transform $A$ to B in the worst case? After analysing some algorithms my guess is that $m \sim n^2$ but I cannot find a formal proof.

Comment: So you are doing something like sorting and counting minimal swaps possible? And it seems quite $O(n)$ to me if I understood your intentions.

Comment: Hint: how many inversions can a single swap reverse at best?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Single swap allows only one reversion.
BTW I haven't found how to edit titles.

Answer (score 1):

If your transpositions form a permutation $\pi$ then (using the appropriate convention for multiplication) $A\pi = B$ and so $\pi = A^{-1} B$. This shows that we can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is the identity, and the question now becomes: how many transpositions do we need to multiply in the worst case to get any particular permutation? This might be a question you already know how to answer.